# Delphi component as shown in RAD Studio

Tags: user-interface, delphi, rad-studio

The **"File >New >Other..."** command of the IDE environment, shows the following image:

[image: Option list in RAD Studio/Delphi]

In the image, two areas (A) and (B) are observed. I am interested in using area control **(B)**.

I assumed it was a `TListView` control, but I haven't been able to achieve similar view options as above. Other people have suggested that each of the displayed items (icon, title, and descriptive text) can be inserted inside a common container (`TPanel`, `TFrame`) and "stacked" inside a `TScrollBox`, a possible solution, but I think the Delphi folks may have used something more optimized.

Does anyone know which component has been used to generate that view? Or, does anyone know how to generate such a view?

Comment: You can easily determine things like this for yourself using WinSpy++ or similar.

Answer (score 1):

It is a component called TControlList: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Vcl.ControlList.TControlList

Comment: Thanks **Uwe**, but the screenshot is from my Delphi XE 10.3-Rio and the recommended control was release on 10.4.2
(I guess in 10.3 they used another solution)

Comment: Well, the Delphi IDE was not written in Delphi, it is written in Microsoft C++. So the best you can do is just choose a Delphi component that looks similar.

Comment: @Doug Rudd: Believe me, the Delphi IDE is written in Delphi! They introduced the new control recently because the old one was too sluggish. Probably the reason why it was never made public.